# What is the role of '\n' in fprintf C?

Tags: c, io, printf

I am confused about the role of '\n' in fprintf. I understand that it copies characters into an array and the \n character signals when to stop reading the character in the current buffer. But then, when does it know to make the system call write.

for example, fprintf(stdout,"hello") prints but I never gave the \n character so how does it know to make the system call.

Comment: What system are you using?  It's quite possible you could look up an implementation.

Comment: '\n' just marks the end of a line.  With a line-buffered stream, the system might flush the buffer when a '\n' is reached, but that's not directly related to `fprintf()`.

Comment: If you're writing to terminal, default is line buffering. So \n will cause it to flush the buffer. If you're writing to a file, it is block buffered. In that case, \n will not flush the buffer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system call is made when the channel is synced/flushed. This can be when the buffer is full (try writing a LOT without a `\n` and you'll see output at some point), when a `\n` is seen (IF you have line buffering configured for the channel, which is the default for tty devices), or when a call to `fflush()` is made.

When the path is closed, it will be flushed as well. When the process terminates, the operating system will close any open paths it has. Each of these events will lead to the system call to emit the output happening.

Comment: but I don't make any call to fflush so how doe it still make the system call.

Comment: @user3213348 I gave three conditions for how the call can be made, but there's a forth also: when the channel is closed, its buffer will be flushed.

Comment: so at the end of the program, the stdout channel is automatically closed? like after there is no more code to execute

Comment: That's correct; part of the OS cleanup is to close any open I/O paths the terminated process has.

Comment: Thank you. This answer is very well explained.

Comment: The fourth condition should be added to this otherwise good answer.

Comment: Spot on now. Good job

Comment: Another `\n` attribute: `'\n'`, on a file opened in text mode, will get written as `'\n'`, `'\r'` and `'\n'`, or maybe something else like `'\r'`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `fprintf("hello");` isn't correct, it should be for instance `fprintf(stdout, "hello");`. Next, \n doesn't implies to stop reading or writing characters, because \n is itself a character, the linefeed ([10th in ascii table](http://4toc.com/fb/FBHelp/gfx/AppF_ASCIITable.png)).

Answer (score 0):

***The assumptions you've stated*** about the purpose and use of `\n` are wrong.  `\n` is simply one of 255 ASCII characters that are *read*, i.e. they are not commands, or directives, that *cause* anything to happen, they are just passive characters that when used in various C functions (eg. sprintf(), printf(), fprintf(), etc.) are interpreted such that presentation of output is manipulated to appear in the desired way.

***By the way***, `\n` (new line) is in good company with many other formatting codes which you can see represented ***[HERE](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output)***